# triggering EC2 autoscaling by using SNS

Tags: amazon-ec2

I need to trigger the EC2 autoscaling from the SNS subscription. Is there any way to do that something like triggering LAMBDA function. Thanks

I have created the SNS Topic and receing the messages from Alertmanager which is configured for CPU, Memory and thread count. I wish to enable the auto scaling based on the SNS topic and not using the cloudwatch events.

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger the EC2 autoscaling from the SNS subscription"? What would you expect a message sent to SNS to do to the Auto Scaling group? How would Auto Scaling know what to do (eg scale-in or scale-out)? Feel free to edit your question to add more details.

Comment: I am generating the alert message (for CPU, Memory and Thread count) in the alert manager and sending to SNS. Now i want the auto-scaling should be initiated (terminate the old instances and spin-up the new)  whenever the alert message received in SNS

Comment: What is "alert manager"? How are these alerts being generated?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling is designed to work by **responding to Amazon CloudWatch Alarms**. When an alarm enters the *ALARM* state, it can trigger Auto Scaling to add or remove instances.

Alternatively, Auto Scaling can **track a particular metric** and will scale to keep that metric close to a given target. For example, an average CPU Utilization of 60% across the group.

If you do not wish to use CloudWatch Alarms to trigger scaling, then you can **write your own logic** and call `SetDesiredCapacity()` to change the number of desired instances, or call `ExecutePolicy()` to trigger a pre-defined scaling policy (eg "add 1 instance").